# как на php преобразовывать ссылки

Tags: php

как сделать вместо http://www/catalog?=1&productId=123 вот это http://www/catalog/chesalka-dlya-jopi ?

Comment: www/catalog - WTF???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это делается не на пхп, а в .htaccess с помощью mod_rewrite:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule catalog/([^/]*) catalog.php?aliace=$1

в результате получишь по ссылке http://www.site.ru/catalog/chesalka-dlya-jopi в скрипте
$_GET['aliace'] == 'chesalka-dlya-jopi'

правила нужно смотреть исходя из реализации кода, и чтобы их писать - нужно знать регулярки

и ещё:
http://www.site.ru/catalog/chesalka.jpg - не выдаст картинки, а погонит в catalog.php, для этого надо писать правила исключений